# Default Servlet for WAS liberty

Tags: servlets, websphere-liberty

In my REST API project I have mapped `/*` to RESTServlet and there is a requirement host static content within the same WAR. I would prefer to map `/static/*` to the default servlet provided by WAS liberty. But I am unable to figure out how to provide that mapping here. Request you help solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set an file serving attribute named "file.serving.patterns.allow" in your ibm-web-ext.xml with the mapping you want.

For more information on file serving attribute see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_flserv.html

For some example snippets from an ibm-web-ext.xml see:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rweb_jspengine.html